# Regex for non zero negative decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using `^-\d*\.?\d+$` for negative number matching. But this accepts -0.
I want to restrict the regexp from matching -0. Can some one help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the number is -0.234, that is, the number starts with zero but is nonzero. Don't you want to get this number?

Comment: i want that number to match. i dont want any match like -0, -0.000, -00000000 etc.. anything which is zero should not match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
^-(?!0*\.?0+$)\d*\.?\d+$
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oopAHy/3)

The `(?!0*\.?0+$)` negative lookahead fails the match if the string only contains `-`, and then an int/float like number that represents a zero.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?!0*\.?0+$)` -  after the current position, fail the match if the following pattern is matched:

  - `0*` - zero or more `0`s
  - `\.?` - an optional `.`
  - `0+` - 1 or more `0`s
  - `$` - end of string
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Regex isn't the correct tool.

```
var input = "-1234"; // or whatever

var num = +input;
if( isNaN(num)) throw new Error("Invalid input");
if( num >= 0) throw new Error("Only negative numbers allowed");
// num is a valid negative number. Done.
```